# Wordpress media upload pop up doesn't show upload form

Tags: jquery, wordpress, popup

I'm having trouble locating the problem for this one. When I try to upload an image using the add media button, the pop up doesn't show the upload form. Clearing the browser cache seems to fix the problem temporarily but the problem comes back after a few hours. [image]

Edit:

Chrome is returning this error:
Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.

Comment: Are you doing anything funny with https?

Comment: No, not really. I guess the problem is with the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: Everything should be loaded from the same domain. Can you use developer tools to check what's going on with your domains?